# How to require an icon from the res folder in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using a ToolbarAndroid component on my react native project. I would like to know how to require an icon, such as the "ic_launcher.png",  from the "projectFolder/android/app/source/main/res/**" directories. I think React Native knows which icon is most appropriate to use. I don't want to use any font library such as "react-native-vector-icons".

Appreciate any help.

My code **Toolbar.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  ToolbarAndroid
} from 'react-native';

const Toolbar = () => (
  <ToolbarAndroid
    logo={require('./ic_launcher.png')}
    title="AwesomeApp"
    actions={[
      {
        title: 'Settings',
        icon: require('./ic_launcher.png'),
        show: 'always'
      }]}
  />
);

export default Toolbar;
```

Comment: you `require('./ic_launcher.png')`, so ic_launcher.png should be at the root of your project, not the res directory. If you want it at the res directory, then change to `require('./path/to/ic_launcher.png')` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, require('./ic_launcher.png'), so ic_launcher.png should be at the root of your project, not the res directory. If you want it at the res directory, then change to require('./path/to/ic_launcher.png') should work.

1. put ic_launcher.png at the projectFolder
2. then build

Here is my test code:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
    logo={require('./1.jpg')}
    title="AwesomeApp"
    onIconClicked={()=>{this.props.nav.pop();}}
    actions={[
        {
            title: 'Settings',
            icon: require('./1.jpg'),
            show: 'always'
        }
    ]}
    style={styles.toolbar}
/>
```

It works, **BTW**, your code should set ToolbarAndroid's height, or it won't displayed.

[image]

Comment: Hi @KaiWen, thank you for the answer, this works fine. However, I would like to know how React Native handles icons on "res" directories. On a native app, Android knows how the best "res" image to use. How react handles this issue?

Comment: @PabloDarde May this help you, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html "You can also use the `@2x` and `@3x` suffixes to provide images for different screen densities...the packager will bundle and serve the image corresponding to device's screen density. For example, `check@2x.png`, will be used on an iPhone 7, while `check@3x.png` will be used on an iPhone 7 Plus or a Nexus 5. If there is no image matching the screen density, the closest best option will be selected."